# 8 bits assembly signed multiplication

Tags: assembly, inline-assembly

I didn't know how to complete this question:

Write an assembly program to perform all the signed combination of 8X8 bits. Remember, we have signed 16X16 bits operation but we don't have for 8X8 bits. Also, you have to use MUL in your program.

This what I did:

```
ORG $2000
MULTIA LDDA #$60
   BMI CMPA
MULTIB LDDB #$A5
   BMI CMPB

MORE ........


CMP NEGA
    BRA MULTIB
CMPB NEGB
    BRA MORE
```

My problem is, if i multiplied the numbers, I didn't know how to let the program to take the 2nd complement of the answer because this is not needed for all cases.

I am using HC12/9S12 assembly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 16x16 signed multiply then all you have to do is sign-extend the inputs to 16 bits and truncate the output to 8 bits (possibly detect overflow). You don't need 2's complement conversion anywhere. You'd need that if you only had unsigned multiply. Nevertheless to answer that question too: you just flip all bits and add one.